# Small spot in web page appears only in google chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

Chrome is getting me crazy. Maybe I'm stupid but I don't understand why chrome shows the green stain under the title (top left). And I say Chrome because the stain does not appear neither in Firefox nor in Explorer (tried all combinations in three different computers). To make things worse, the stain sometimes disappear if I refresh the page.

Maybe there's an error in the page and chrome is unable to fix it while the others do?

I know this is not very important but it is very annoying and I'd like to know what's going on.

You can [see it for yourself](http://wordpressdrupal.com).

[image: page screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a link to http://wordpressdrupal.com/#

It is a text: wordpresstodrupal, which also appears on Safari.

Probably it is caused by a css trick that tríes to hide it.

Comment: That's correct! It was the text inside the h1 that chrome was trying to display. So stupid but so difficult to find when you are the only one looking at the html!

Comment: In chrome you can right click and choose Inspect element on any problem parts of the page and it will take you directly to the part of the html, displaying the css info next to it. This helps to identify problems faster

Answer (score 3):

It's the `<a/>` inside the `<h1 id="logo"/>` element. If you don't need it, remove it. If you need it to be in the HTML, but shouldn't be visible, hide it: `h1#logo a { display: none }`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the stain you talk of is the anchor text(Wordpress to Drupal) of the link you have within `<h1 id="logo">`

To get rid of it, delete the text. If you want you could add it to the link by using the `title=""`  attribute.